# Expect on value assigned from promise (Jest unittest)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jestjs, es6-class

I'm unittesting a es6 class and want my test to verify the values written to the class variables.

My class has the folowing method:

```
export default class ctrl{
    constructor(){}

    postClosingNote(payload) {
        this._headerNoteService.createNewNote(payload).then(data => {
            this.note = {};
            this.claimNotes = data;
            this.returnToClaimHeader();
        });
    }
}
```

Service method:

```
createNewNote(postData){
        return this._http.post(`${api}`, postData).then(res => res.data);
    }
```

Unittest:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
         when(headerNoteService.createNewNote).calledWith(newNote).mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({'claimNotes': 'txt'}));
    });

const newNote = {
    text: "txt",
    claimDescriptionTypeId: 4,
    claimHeaderId: headerId
};

test('Confirm that newly submitted note is added to the headers notes', () => {
    target = new ctrl();
    target.postClosingNote(newNote);
    expect(target.claimNotes).toEqual({'claimNotes': 'txt'});
});
```

Output from running test:

```
Expected value to equal:
  {"claimNotes": "txt"}
Received:
  undefined
```

logging target to console does not include any reference to `this.note` or `this.claimNotes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is happening because `postClosingNote()` returns immediately before the promise is resolved. You need to wait for it to resolve before testing the result. You can return the promise from `postClosingNote` and wait it to resolve in your test.

(haven't actually run this code, there might be syntax errors but you get the idea):

```
postClosingNote(payload) {
    return this._headerNoteService.createNewNote(payload).then(data => {
        this.note = {};
        this.claimNotes = data;
        this.returnToClaimHeader();
    });
}
```

Unittest:

```
test('Confirm that newly submitted note is added to the headers notes', () => {
    target = new ctrl();
    target.postClosingNote(newNote).then(result => {
        expect(target.claimNotes).toEqual({'claimNotes': 'txt'});
    }
});
```

Comment: I had forgot 'return' before the method call and could not get you solution to work. That's why I posted my own solution

Answer (score 0):

Using async/await worked:

```
test('Confirm that newly submitted note is added to the headers notes', async () => {
    target = new ctrl();
    await target.postClosingNote(newNote);
    expect(target.claimNotes).toEqual({'claimNotes': 'txt'});
});
```